# Reconstruct a dataframe from a contingency table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I would like to reconstruct a dataframe from a contingency table stored as dataframe. For example from `ctab` I would like to build `df1` or `df2`. Is there a command to do that
or do I need a loop?

```
import pandas as pd
ctab = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [2, 1]], columns=["A", "B"], index=["A", "B"])
print(ctab)
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A","A", 1], ["A","B", 2], ["B","A", 2], ["B","B", 1]], columns=["col", "index", "freq"])
print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["A","A"], ["A","B"], ["A","B"], ["B","A"], ["B","A"], ["B","B"]], columns=["col", "index"])
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html), [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
out = ctab.rename_axis(index='index', columns='col').stack().reset_index(name='freq')
```

Output:

```
  index col  freq
0     A   A     1
1     A   B     2
2     B   A     2
3     B   B     1
```

For the second one, replicate the rows with [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html):

```
out = ctab.rename_axis(index='index', columns='col').stack().reset_index(name='freq')

out = out.loc[out.index.repeat(out.pop('freq'))]
```

Output:

```
  index col
0     A   A
1     A   B
1     A   B
2     B   A
2     B   A
3     B   B
```